# How can I run commands like setfsuid, setfsgid as a normal user?

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

Normally only the root user has permission to run these commands. Is any way I can run these as a normal user?

Answer (score 0):

No. They're inherently privileged system calls; only root can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. You have to find a [*vulnerability*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_%28computing%29) and exploit it, or specify a `uid_t` that you are or were.